# Rails search all columns of db for value without explicitly naming them

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

If I want to search a a set of columns for a value, then I can do something like this:

```
MyModel.where do
 col1.matches("%#{search[:search_key]}%") | col2.matches("%#{search[:search_key]}%") | ...
end
```

But when I want to search all columns of the table, it shouldn't be necessary to explicitly name them all in my query right? Because otherwise every time I add a column to my database, I'll have to add it to my search query too.

Is there a way to just search all the columns of a table for a value. So something like this:

```
MyModel.search_all_columns(search[:search_key])
```

So basically what angular filter does.

Comment: There is no built-in solution for that.

Comment: This looks like full text search. There are specialized fast engines for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyModel.where do
  MyModel.columns.map do |col|
    col.matches("%#{search[:search_key]}%")
  end.reduce :|
end
```

or use `ActiveRecord::Base#column_names` to build a query.